# Can I use my old smartphone like raspberry pi by installing raspberry pi OS to it

Tags: python, android

> I have an old dell aero smartphone, which is currently having Android
>   1.5 Os. Can I flash the phone and install Raspbian or any linux?to make use of it..

The touchscreen is not working for that phone, so I can only see the screen, touch input does not work. I don't know whether this question is valid or not or the flashing of the phone is possible or not. If anyone know anything about this.. Kindly share

If any other solutions to make use of the parts of the phone are also welcome..
:|

Comment: What does this have to do with the Pi, other than as a tool for comparison.

Comment: That is not what your question says, the question asks if you can install python - edit your question and vote to reopen and we will consider reopening it. Note that this is very likely impossible for a myriad of reasons.

Comment: I would like to -1 this Question or flag it for a Moderator to close as **Wildly Off-topic** - however since someone has taken the time to provide a concise reply and Mr Steve has already seen it and not consigned it to wherever rejected questions go; I'll just move on...

Comment: @SlySven _fiddling_ with stuff that would otherwise be _junk_ is one of the reasons why I RPi, so I think if this where re-written as a list of hardware that was salvaged from the Android device, with questions regarding how to connect bits to an RPi that I'd +1 it, further more I think if such changes where made by the OP that it would encourage answers more along the lines of what [@Bill K](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53639/8651) was getting at. Because there's lot's of upcycling potential beyond display or shell access; camera(s), LEDs, buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not going to work, but you could use the screen to display a pi desktop over vnc or rdp

There are a few ways to leverage your phone.. if you just want Python there is probably an app for that.  You may be able to find a Linux distribution (raspian is just a version of Linux)

You could duct tape a pi 3 to the back of your phone, configure it as a wifi hotspot, ssh in from the phone, tape the whole mess to a Bluetooth keyboard and use vi to code Python like some Frankenstein's monster--the possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry PI family run on **BCM2835** ARM6 512kB or **BCM2836** ARM7 1.0GB  *peripheral controller*.

Installing `Raspbian` on any other processor, will operate just like any other Linux, without the rPI functionality (GPIO), so will defeat the purpose; drivers required to handle your phone will not be preconfigured, finally, the boot process on a phone is significantly different than on the rPI.

So, the answer is **no**, keep using your phone as a paper weight.

Comment: Alternatively, be nice to the planet and recycle the phone.

Comment: I did disassemble my phone and took some of its components.. like battery, speaker etc. Those are of good use now.

Comment: @sarath [`adb`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=199977) (Android Debug Bridge) is available in the Raspbian repository, eg. `apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot` _should_ enable communications with Android over USB from RPi. Meaning that if your phone's USB port is still connected to the board it should be possible to use it's CPU and other components too... Getting root is tougher if the screen was fully removed; might be possible if documented thoroughly on XDA Forums, but given the stated Android version that'll likely lead to a lot of dead links.

Answer (score -1):

Yes u may not be able to install raspberry pi is on your Smartphone but u could use janOS  to convert your phone into an IOT board
Refer- http://janos.io/